# Uncaught ReferenceError: with bower-component

Tags: javascript, d3.js, require

I used Require and Bower to link JS libraries - jQuery, Underscore, Moment, and d3. I have no problem in loading libraries, except D3. It sometimes works, but randomly Chrome shows this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined"

I am not sure where the problem comes from, since it seems to happen randomly when I refresh browser.

The entire error messages are like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined 
(anonymous function)require.js:29 
i.execCbrequire.js:18 
Z.checkrequire.js:23 
Z.enablerequire.js:17 
Z.initrequire.js:14 
Erequire.js:28 
i.completeLoadrequire.js:29 
i.onScriptLoad
```

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I doubt it. It works fine on Safari.

Comment: Also when I refresh the Chrome browser after editing main.js (the linked file from Require), it doesn't update. But updates fine on Safari.